# can not update label text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to get a simple GUI running that simply changes a labels text every few seconds. I'm new to using tkinter and don't understand how every thing works but from what I've gathered online the after() method SHOULD be calling the function I wrote to change the label text but it's not working?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.title("Blank")
root.geometry("480x240")

label = Label(
    root,
    text = "hello",
    font = ("Arial", 42)
)

label.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)

def updater():
    label.config(text = "Test 1")
    time.sleep(1)
    label.config(text = "Test 2")

root.mainloop()
root.after(2000, updater)
```

Comment: Never ever use `time.sleep` in a GUI program. This will block the mainloop, which will prevent the label from updating. But more importantly, your `root.after` isn't executed until the mainloop ends - in other words, until you close the window.

Comment: You should maybe put the `label.config` that comes after `time.sleep` in a lambda function which is inside a `root.after` (like this : `root.after(1000, lambda: label.config(text = "Test 2"))`

Comment: I removed the time.sleep() and tried using a lambda function instead but neither one works. I'm really confused at this point, I don't understand why it doesn't just work.

Comment: Did you move the call to `root.mainloop()` after the call to `root.after` as indicated by @Aran-Fey?

Comment: Alright, after moving the .after() call it now changes the label text. But now my other problem is how to get it to keep changing from one string to another?

Comment: Call `.after()` at the end of `updater()` function to repeat changing the label periodically.

Answer (score 1):

Actually just figured it out myself. The working code now looks like this:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.title("Blank")
root.geometry("480x240")

label = Label(
    root,
    text = " ",
    font = ("Arial", 42)
)

label.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = True)

def changeString1():
    label.config(text = "Test 1")
    label.after(1000, changeString2)

def changeString2():
    label.config(text = "Test 2")
    label.after(1000, changeString1)


changeString1()
root.mainloop()
```

Again as I'm new to tkinter I have no idea if this is an acceptable solution but it works so I'm happy.